# Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{k=4n}(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}k^2$.Prove that $S_n=4n(4n+1).$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{k=4n}(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}k^2$.Prove that $S_n=4n(4n+1).$

---

$S_n=-(1)^2-(2)^2+(3)^2+(4)^2-(5)^2-(6)^2+(7)^2+(8)^2-....-(4n-3)^2-(4n-2)^2+(4n-1)^2+(4n)^2$
How to sum up now,I am stuck.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that factoring as difference of squares we get 
\begin{align}
-(4n-3)^2-(4n-2)^2+(4n-1)^2+(4n)^2&=[(4n-1)^2-(4n-3)^2]+[(4n)^2-(4n-2)^2]\\
&=2(8n-4)+2(8n-2)\\
&=32n-12
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
S_n&=32\sum_{k=1}^nk-12n\\
&=32\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-12n\\
&=4n(4n+4-3)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sum_{r=4s+1}^{4s+4}=-(4s+1)^2-(4s+2)^2+(4s+3)^2+(4s+4)^2$$

$$=(4s+4)^2-(4s+1)^2+(4s+3)^2-(4s+2)^2$$

$$=(3+1)(8s+5)$$

$4s+1=1\iff s=0,4s+4=4n\iff s=n-1$